# IMPLEMENTAR AJAX EN ARQUITECTURA MVC php

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

tengo una duda de como implementar ajax en MVC de php.
mi estructura de archivos es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se en que directorio deberia usar las peticiones ajax

Comment: Si estas implementando un sistema donde las partes se marcan por sus funciones, te recomiendo que hagas los ajax en archivos js , no dentro de archivos php, para que le des una estructura mas ordenada a tu proyecto, después basta con importar los script .Saludos.

Comment: Sebastián gracias por tu respuesta, por favor me podrías dar un ejemplo mas claro, y en que directorio de mi proyecto especificamente crearia los js

Comment: crea dentro de la carpeta js

Comment: Hace mas de un año desarrolle un mini-framework con PHP nativo, esta en MVC y esta inspiradoen otros framework, aqui realizo peticiones ajax para el uso de la librería DataTable y otras peticiones, puede apoyarte e interesarte, saludos. https://github.com/Oscabrera/Framework-MVC-PHP-puro.git